# Why I can see vehicles in red highlight

Tags: battlefield-hardline

During some multiplayer session (Hotwire, should that matter) I spotted helicopters and - less frequently - cars highlighted in red, but I can't figure out why.

I've been playing Battlefield 3 and 4 a lot, but as far as I can remember I cannot recall anything like that, it seems something new.

Could someone please explain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I figured it out.

When you hit an enemy vehicle or player with the tracking dart, it appears highlighted in red and it is permanently marked on the minimap. But beyond that, if a vehicle is hit by a tracking dart it can be acquired as a target from smart aiming weapons.

[image: Battlefield Hardline - Tracking Dart]

It is a new weapon, not present in Battlefield 4 so I was unaware of its behaviour.

Comment: Nice to know, thanks didn't not yet see such a mark it seems^^

Comment: This weapon also was used in Battlefield BC2. Only RPG and SMAW can lock to tracking dart marked vehicle/soldier.

Answer (score 1):

There can be 2 reasons even if i dont know if both get a red highlighting

**1. Hotwire Game Mode**

> Hotwire is an objective game mode in Battlefield Hardline. It's basically a mobile, high-speed version of Conquest.
>
> The criminals are trying to steal a list of marked Vehicles while the cops are trying to repossess them. These marked cars are the main objective points of the game mode. Get inside a marked vehicle and drive around at high speeds to "capture" them.

**2. Spotting**

> Spotting is a useful tactic in Battlefield Hardline's Multiplayer. Use
> the spot button while looking at an enemy Agent or vehicle to tag them
> for your team. If an Agent is tagged, they will have a red upside-down
> triangle over their head. If a vehicle is tagged, they will be marked
> with a red star and a small red icon of the vehicle.

I've to say that i just played the beta but never the released version so it could have been changed from beta to release.